# Allow ufw ports for PREROUTING, but not publicly visible

Tags: ufw

I have the following mapping set-up for `ufw`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
36022                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
36022 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I only have `8080` and `8443` open because my Go app runs both `0.0.0.0:8080` and `0.0.0.0:8443`. My domain gets called on `80` and `443` and `ufw` does `PREROUTING` to the internal ports.

It's not a safety concern perse, but I would love to make `https://example.com:8443` not publicly visible. Even tho it's the same as the normal `https://example.com` it would be nice to simply keep the `8080` and `8443` ports internally.

I tried this for both `8080` and `8443` and on both `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0`:

```
ufw allow from 127.0.0.1 proto tcp to any port 8443
```

..but this doesn't seem to work. The website then times out on `http://example.com` and `https://example.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work when you deactivate ufw ? What do the logs show for blocked traffic ?

Comment: It works in general. But `PREROUTING` requires `8080` and `8443` to be open to as they're are routed to on the server's own network itself. So running the initial list I posted `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` work fine. But `http://example.com:8080` and `https://example.com:8443` also work, and I'd love to hide that from the public. So instead of `8080/tcp` and `8443/tcp` on `Anywhere` I need to it to stay inside the server-computer, yet having it on either `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` as the IP the normal `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` stop responding and timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Some clarification. All rules that you listed are `INPUT`. When you `enable` you `UFW` you also do `enable` and

```
XXX@XXX:~$ sudo ls /etc/ufw/
after6.rules  after.rules     before6.rules  before.rules  ufw.conf     user.rules
after.init    applications.d  before.init    sysctl.conf   user6.rules
```

And so on ...

Very simple, maybe stupid, explanation of rules processing is

- packet com to interface
- applying `before.rules` aka `PREROUTING`
- applying `user.ruler` aka `INPUT`
- applaying `after.rules` - `POSTRUTING`
- ...

Whit listed rules you do not apply any `PREROUTING`

`IPTABLES` do that on this way

[image]

Private aka non public address is

```
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 | 10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 | 172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 | 192.168.0.0/16
```

If you wont to allow access from this address and not from public, create rules

```
ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/8 proto tcp to any port 8443
ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/8 proto tcp to any port 8080
ufw allow from 172.16.0.0/12 proto tcp to any port 8443
ufw allow from 172.16.0.0/12 proto tcp to any port 8080
ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16 proto tcp to any port 8443
ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16 proto tcp to any port 8080
ufw allow port 80
ufw allow port 443
```

This rules will allow connection from `private network` on port `8443` and `8080`and deny access from `public network`on this port but allow `80` and `443` from anywhere . `Private network` are not routed through the internet but it is routed on local network.

`UFW` `allow` or `deny` traffic based on `ip address`, `protocol` or/and `port`

If you are behind some router with `nat` then you must create different rule the your router do not do nat ...

Maybe I do not understand you.

EDIT 1

Maybe is better to allow access only from local network on port `8080` and `8443`

```
ufw allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/YY proto tcp to any port 8443
ufw allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/YY proto tcp to any port 8080
```

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/YY - is you local network

One more thing. Oreder of the ruler is also important

ufw deny from ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ/XX proto tcp to any port 8443
   ufw allow 8443

This set of rules deny access only from network ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ/XX on port `8443` using `tcp` and allow from all other network.